How to enable light/dark separately for different pages?
I am creating a basic todo list application using functional and class components. I have used react-router have link to the respective code containing todo list code containing functional/class components. I was also exploring useContext to enable light/dark mode on these pages. I was successful in doing so. This light/dark at the moment is acting universally. So whether I enable it in one page, it shows the same theme in the other page.
Now, I want to enable it in such a way that the theme switching is separate for each page. So whether I enable dark mode in the FunctionalToDo code, it should still remain light mode in the ClassToDo code. The default is light mode. How to do so?
FuntionalToDo.jsx
// FunctionalToDo.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Button, Checkbox, TextField, List, ListItem, ListItemText, IconButton, Typography, Container, CssBaseline, Box
} from '@mui/material';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import { useTheme } from '../components/themeContext';
import '../components/styles.css';

const FunctionalToDo = () => {
  const task = useRef('');
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const editIndexRef = useRef(-1);
  const { theme } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Functional: Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        const initialTasks = data.slice(0, 25).map(todo => ({
          id: crypto.randomUUID(),
          text: todo.title,
          completed: todo.completed,
        }));
        setTasks(initialTasks);
        console.log('Functional: Data fetched successfully:', initialTasks);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Functional: Error fetching data:', error);
        setIsError(true);
      }
    })();
    console.log('Functional: Component did mount');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Functional: Tasks state updated');
  }, [tasks]);

  const handleTask = useCallback(() => {
    if (task.current) {
      setTasks(prevTasks => {
        if (editIndexRef.current !== -1) {
          const updatedTasks = [...prevTasks];
          updatedTasks[editIndexRef.current].text = task.current;
          return updatedTasks;
        } else {
          const newTask = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: task.current, completed: false };
          return [...prevTasks, newTask];
        }
      });
      editIndexRef.current = -1;
      task.current = '';
      inputRef.current.value = '';
    }
  }, []);

  const handleClearTasks = useCallback(() => {
    setTasks([]);
  }, []);

  const taskList = useMemo(() => tasks.map((item) => (
    <ListItem key={item.id} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Checkbox
        id={item.id}
        checked={item.completed}
        onChange={() => {
          const updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => (
            task.id === item.id ? { ...task, completed: !task.completed } : task
          ));
          setTasks(updatedTasks);
        }}
      />
      <ListItemText
        primary={item.text}
        style={{ textDecoration: item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}
      />
      <IconButton onClick={() => {
        const taskToEdit = tasks.find(task => task.id === item.id);
        task.current = taskToEdit.text;
        editIndexRef.current = tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === item.id);
        inputRef.current.value = taskToEdit.text;
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }}>
        <EditIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={() => {
        const updatedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.id !== item.id);
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
      }}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItem>
  )), [tasks]);

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container
        className={`container ${theme.functional === 'dark' ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}`}
      >
        <Typography variant="h3" align="center" gutterBottom>
          ToDo App - Functional Component
        </Typography>
        {isError && (
          <Typography variant="h6" align="center" color="error">
            Error fetching data. Please try again later.
          </Typography>
        )}
        <TextField
          label="Enter task"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
          inputRef={inputRef}
          onChange={(e) => { task.current = e.target.value }}
        />
        <Box textAlign="center">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleTask}
            style={{ marginBottom: '20px', marginRight: '10px' }}
          >
            {editIndexRef.current !== -1 ? 'Update Task' : 'Add Task'}
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            onClick={handleClearTasks}
            style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
          >
            Clear All Tasks
          </Button>
        </Box>
        <List>{taskList}</List>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default FunctionalToDo;

ClassToDo.jsx
// ClassToDo.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button, Checkbox, TextField, List, ListItem, ListItemText, IconButton, Typography, Container, CssBaseline, Box
} from '@mui/material';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import { useTheme } from '../components/themeContext';
import '../components/styles.css';

class ClassToDo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      task: '',
      tasks: [],
      editIndex: -1,
      isError: false,
    };
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Class: Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        const initialTasks = data.slice(0, 25).map(todo => ({
          id: crypto.randomUUID(),
          text: todo.title,
          completed: todo.completed,
        }));
        this.setState({ tasks: initialTasks });
        console.log('Class: Data fetched successfully:', initialTasks);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Class: Error fetching data:', error);
        this.setState({ isError: true });
      }
    })();
  
    console.log('Class: Component did mount');
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('Class: ComponentDidUpdate: Component has updated.');
    if (prevState.tasks !== this.state.tasks) {
      console.log('Class: Tasks state updated');
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Class: ComponentWillUnmount: Component is about to be unmounted.');
  }

  handleAddTask = () => {
    const { task, tasks, editIndex } = this.state;
    if (task) {
      if (editIndex !== -1) {
        const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
        updatedTasks[editIndex].text = task;
        this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks, editIndex: -1, task: '' });
      } else {
        const newTask = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: task, completed: false };
        this.setState({ tasks: [...tasks, newTask], task: '' });
      }
    }
  }

  handleClearTasks = () => {
    this.setState({ tasks: [] });
  }

  renderItem = (item, index) => (
    <ListItem key={item.id} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Checkbox
        id={item.id}
        checked={item.completed}
        onChange={() => {
          const updatedTasks = this.state.tasks.map(task => (
            task.id === item.id ? { ...task, completed: !task.completed } : task
          ));
          this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks });
        }}
      />
      <ListItemText
        primary={item.text}
        style={{ textDecoration: item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}
      />
      <IconButton onClick={() => {
        const taskToEdit = this.state.tasks[index];
        this.setState({ task: taskToEdit.text, editIndex: index });
        this.inputRef.current.focus(); // Focus on the input field when editing
      }}>
        <EditIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={() => {
        const updatedTasks = this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== item.id);
        this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks });
      }}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItem>
  );

  render() {
    const { task, tasks, isError } = this.state;
    const { theme } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Container
          className={`container ${theme === 'dark' ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}`}
        >
          <Typography variant="h3" align="center" gutterBottom>
            ToDo App - Class Component
          </Typography>
          {isError && (
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center" color="error">
              Error fetching data. Please try again later.
            </Typography>
          )}
          <TextField
            label="Enter task"
            variant="outlined"
            value={task}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ task: e.target.value })}
            fullWidth
            style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
            inputRef={this.inputRef}
          />
          <Box textAlign="center">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={this.handleAddTask}
              style={{ marginBottom: '20px', marginRight: '10px' }}
            >
              {this.state.editIndex !== -1 ? 'Update Task' : 'Add Task'}
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={this.handleClearTasks}
              style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
            >
              Clear All Tasks
            </Button>
          </Box>
          <List>{tasks.map((item, index) => this.renderItem(item, index))}</List>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedClassToDo = (props) => (
  <ClassToDo {...props} theme={useTheme().theme.class} />
);

export default WrappedClassToDo;

index.jsx
//index.jsx
import React from "react";
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';
import App from './App';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { ThemeProvider } from './components/themeContext';
import './components/styles.css';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

App.jsx
//App.jsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Switch, Button, Container, Box } from '@mui/material';
import FunctionalToDo from './pages/FunctionalToDo';
import ClassToDo from './pages/ClassToDo';
import { useTheme } from './components/themeContext';
import './components/styles.css';

const TopBar = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useTheme();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          ToDo App
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate('/functional')}>
          Functional
        </Button>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => navigate('/class')}>
          Class
        </Button>
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
          <Typography variant="body1" style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
            Dark Mode
          </Typography>
          <Switch
            checked={theme === 'dark'}
            onChange={toggleTheme}
          />
        </Box>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = theme === 'dark' ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode';
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <TopBar />
      <Container maxWidth="sm" className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" />
          <Route path="/functional" element={<FunctionalToDo />} />
          <Route path="/class" element={<ClassToDo />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;

styles.css
/* styles.css */

/* Reset styles */
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

/* Light mode styles */
body.light-mode {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

/* Dark mode styles */
body.dark-mode {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Additional styling */
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Dark and light mode styles for specific components can also be added */
.container.dark-mode {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

themeContext.jsx
//themeContext.jsx
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(prevTheme => (prevTheme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);


I suppose the trivial solution is to wrap each route (or group of routes) in its own theme provider so they are independently themed from other routes (or groups of routes). What have you tried already in creating separately themed pages?

You can achieve this by storing the theme value as an object using the page name as a key rather than storing it as a string.
themeContext.jsx
//themeContext.jsx
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({classToDo:'light', functionalToDo:'light'});

  const toggleTheme = (page) => {
    setTheme(prevTheme => ({
     ...prevTheme,
     [page]:prevTheme[page] === 'light'? 'dark' : 'light'
    }));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

So everywhere where you are using the theme value from useTheme to determine whether it's currently light or dark, you need to update it to either theme.classToDO or theme.functionalToDo depending on the page.
